# Modificar tipo fichero temporal

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente parte del código:

```
public void SendAttachment(Stream responseContent, string mime, string fileName)
        {
            lock (DecoratedContext.Response)
            {
                DecoratedContext.Response.ClearContent();
                DecoratedContext.Response.ClearHeaders();

               // DecoratedContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;filename=" + fileName);
               // DecoratedContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", mime);
                DecoratedContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", responseContent.Length.ToString());
                DecoratedContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

               DecoratedContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                DecoratedContext.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.xlsx");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

                int readCount = 1;


                while (readCount > 0)
                {
                    readCount = responseContent.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    DecoratedContext.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                }
                DecoratedContext.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();


                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();
            }
        }
```

Esta clase es la que llama al SenAttachment

```
protected override void Execute_Internal(ref CommandExecutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Accidentes != null)
        {
            Report report = GetReport();

            if (report.Name != "CercaBasica" && report.Name != "CercaAvancada")
            {
                Stream output = report.GetReportOutput();

                HttpResponseDecorator response = EnvironmentGateway.INSTANCE.Context.DecoratedResponse;

                response.SendAttachment(output, OutputMIME, OutputFileName);
                output.Flush();
                output.Dispose();
                output.Close();

                report.ExportStrategy.DeleteTemporaryFiles();
            }
```

Hay la posibilidad de poder cambiar la extensión de mi fichero temporal? O cerrarlo antes de enviarlo para que el usuario lo guarde en su pc?

Ahora mismo de la forma que esta coge un archivo .tmp lo guarda como xls.

Puedo antes de hacer esto modificarlo a xlsx?

gracias!

Comment: como estas generando el responseContent ? eso no los muestras en el codigo, solo se ve que lo envias en el response para la descarga

Comment: Añado más info :) gracias!!

Comment: Ya me dirás @LeandroTuttini